# Can I generate an Image-based PDF report from SQL Reporting Services (.rdlc) with out saving the image anywhere?

Tags: c#, sql-server, pdf-generation, ssrs-2008

**Scenario:**

I have a web page with multiple charts and I have an 'Export to PDF' button that the User should be able to click and it generates a PDF that the User can then save.

**Given:**

A Telerik RadChart that can save itself into a memory stream as such:

```
MemoryStream chartStream = new MemoryStream();
RadChart1.Save(chartStream, ImageFormat.Png);
```

Using this memory stream, is it possible to build a PDF using the SQL Reporting Services **WITH OUT** saving it to a file first **OR** having to insert it into an MSSQL table first?

I will up-vote and/or accept any answer that is an open source or free solution to this problem as well.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you do it in code using the PrintDocument class to a pdf writer on the fly?

Comment: @Paul, good idea but that won't work because we have multiple charts along with some other variable data. I need to build a PDF using either the reporting services (which I think will force me to save all the charts as images or save them in a database table) or another PDF generator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alright, just figured this out.  There are three elements to this answer, two screenshots to follow in order and then some code:

1. Creating a typed dataset to hold the chart image(s)

   [image: Step 1]
2. Hooking the typed dataset up to the RDLC report

   [image: Step 2]
3. The button click code for generating the PDF and streaming it to the browser.

   ```
   protected void btnPDF_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       //Put the image you want to display in a MemoryStream.  You can read an image from the file system
       //or generate an image, etc.  This example renders an image to a memory stream using a custom charting control.
       MemoryStream chtLoginsByMonthStream = new MemoryStream();
       this.chtLoginsByMonth.Save(chtLoginsByMonthStream, ImageFormat.Png);


       //Setup the datatable you will pass into the RDLC
       dsStudentUsage.dtUsageChartsDataTable dt = new dsStudentUsage.dtUsageChartsDataTable();
       dsStudentUsage.dtUsageChartsRow dr = dt.NewdtUsageChartsRow();

       //create new Byte Array, this will hold the image data from the memory stream
       byte[] chtLoginsByMonthArray = new byte[chtLoginsByMonthStream.Length];

       //Set pointer to the beginning of the stream
       chtLoginsByMonthStream.Position = 0;

       //Read the entire stream
       chtLoginsByMonthStream.Read(chtLoginsByMonthArray, 0, (int)chtLoginsByMonthStream.Length);

       //Put the byte array into the new datarow in the appropriate column
       dr["imgLoginsByMonth"] = chtLoginsByMonthArray;
       dt.Rows.Add(dr);

       //Add the data source to the report.
       ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("dsStudentUsage_dtUsageCharts", dt));

       //Setup objects for streaming the PDF to the browser
       Warning[] warnings;
       string[] streamids;
       string mimeType;
       string encoding;
       string extension;
       byte[] bytes;


       //Make a container for all of your report parameters
       var rptList = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
       rptList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("rpTotalLogins", "2,000"));
       //more parameters go here

       //Feed the report parameters into the actual "ReportParameters" class
       ReportParameter[] rptParams = new ReportParameter[rptList.Count];
       for (int i = 0; i < rptList.Count; i++)
       {
           rptParams[i] = new ReportParameter(rptList[i].Key, rptList[i].Value);
       }

       //Set parameters for the report.
       ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(rptParams);

       //Render the report to a byte array in PDF format
       bytes = ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Render("PDF", null, out mimeType, out encoding, out extension, out streamids, out warnings);

       //Set the stream to either prompt user as file download or "inline" to stream
       //PDF directly into the browser window.

       HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=StudentUsageReport.pdf");
       //HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-disposition", "inline;");
       HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
       HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
       HttpContext.Current.Response.End();

   }
   ```

Comment: EPIC! This is EXACTLY what I was looking for. Being able to build a dataset in memory and by passing the database altogether. :)

Answer (score 2):

I have used [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/archive/2006/03/02/How-to-render-client-report-definition-files-_28002E00_rdlc_2900_-directly-to-the-Response-stream-without-preview.aspx) method in the past without issue, and it worked great for me.

Comment: Thanks but thats HOW I would render the PDF and not how to add images without using the database. +1 anyway because this is still useful.

Answer (score 1):

I use iTextSharp for all of my PDF generation. There's a little bit of a learning curve but then it gets pretty easy. Here's some links:

- [Image Array to PDF](http://charlescherry.wordpress.com/2008/04/04/itextsharp-code/)
- [iTextSharp](http://itextsharp.com/)